# How to use RHVoice via Speech Dispatcher in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, text-to-speech

I am trying to use [RHVoice](https://rhvoice.org) in my **Qt C++ project** on a Linux.

I installed [RHVoice](https://rhvoice.org), and I struggled with its library `RHVoice.h`, which is provided by `librhvoice-dev` package, and so far, it seems like a dead end.

Then I found out that **Speech-Dispatcher** supports **RHVoice** module, and [Qt Text To Speech](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qttexttospeech-index.html) supports [Speech-Dispatcher](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qttexttospeech-engines.html#speech-dispatcher), so it seemed like the proper way to use **RHVoice** in **Qt**.

But the Qt documentation says:

> The speech-dispatcher engine does not support any engine specific parameters.

So I cannot make **Speech-Dispatcher** use **RHVoice** through **Qt**, and my question is basically how to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to this is to set **RHVoice** as the default synthesizer for **Speech-Dispatcher**, which can be done as follows:

Modify **Speech-Dispatcher** configuration by modifying the following files:

```
/usr/share/speech-dispatcher/conf/speechd.conf
```

```
/etc/speech-dispatcher/speechd.conf
```

If you want to change the configuration per-user only, editing the following file is enough:

```
~/.config/speech-dispatcher/speechd.conf
```

Change the `DefaultModule` to `rhvoice` as follows:

```
...
# -----OUTPUT MODULES CONFIGURATION-----
...
# The DefaultModule selects which output module is the default.  You
# must use one of the names of the modules loaded with AddModule.

DefaultModule rhvoice
```

save and close, and check if it works in your **Qt** Project, here's an example:

`CMake:`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(RHVoiceSpeechD LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core TextToSpeech)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core TextToSpeech)

add_executable(RHVoiceSpeechD
  main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(RHVoiceSpeechD Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::TextToSpeech)

install(TARGETS RHVoiceSpeechD
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextToSpeech>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTextToSpeech *tts = new QTextToSpeech();

    //set speechd as the engine if it is not the default engine
    tts->setEngine("speechd");

    //test it
    tts->say("I'm using RHVoice as a synthesizer");

    return a.exec();
}
```

Run this command in a terminal:

```
spd-say -o rhvoice "I'm using RHVoice as a synthesizer"
```

and compare the audio output with the one from your **Qt** project, they should sound the same if the previous steps worked, the default voice for RHVoice is "**Alan**".

Sources:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/RHVoice
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qttexttospeech-index.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qttexttospeech-engines.html
- https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/brailcom/speechd/blob/master/doc/speech-dispatcher.html#Top